# npm module not installed error although module is installed

Tags: node.js, npm

Here is the error:

```
>node -v
v0.12.9

>ionic -v
2.0.0-beta.37

>nvm use 4.4.7
now using node v4.4.7

>ionic -v
-bash: ionic: command not found
```

so ionic is installed globally, so why the error if I switch node versions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is expected.
When you install modules globally, you install them in current node version directory.
If you change node version then you also have new directory with global modules.

Solution 1:
Install globals modules to each node version which you use

SOlution 2:
Don't install modules globally (It is recommended by many experienced devs). Install them locally.

Solution 3:
Set common path for all globals modules (you can read how do it here https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)